# $2(n-1)! \equiv -1 \mod n+2 \iff n+2$ is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

***Problem:*** Show that $2(n-1)! \equiv -1 \mod n+2 \iff n+2$ is a prime.

I know that Wilson's theorem states that $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p $ for $p$ a prime, so that is the important thing to know with these type of problems.

I know that $-1 \equiv n+1 \mod n+2$ , 
and that if $n+2$ is prime, then $(n+1)!  = -1 \mod n+2$. So this is all I have for now, any hints appreciated.

Comment: Well, what is $(n+1)\times n\pmod {n+2}$?

Comment: @lulu $(-n) \mod n+2 $

Comment: Yes, and what is $n\pmod {n+2}$?

Comment: @lulu -2 I believe.

Comment: Yes, and what is $-1\times -2$?

Comment: Note:  I expect you are just confused by the awkward use of $n+2$ here.  Perhaps it would clarify things to rewrite the problem using $m=n+2$.

Comment: Ok. I get it now lol, thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the comments since I know that $2 (n-1)! \equiv (-1)(-2)(n-1)! \equiv (n)(n+1)(n-1)! \equiv (n+1)! \equiv -1 \mod (n+2)$, then $n+2$ is prime.

Comment: Just to be clear:  Wilson's Theorem plus the algebraic manipulation you provide just show one direction.  Specifically: they show that $n+2$ prime $\implies 2(n-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod {n+2}$.  You need to show the converse as well.  However, that's pretty easy (Hint:  if $n+2$ is composite then it has a non-trivial factor $<n-1$, at least for $n≥4$).